# Map Right Alt to Spacebar including in key combinations

Tags: xmodmap, remapping

I am working on a laptop with a broken spacebar, so I re-mapped the right alt key to the spacebar with:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_R = space"
```

This works well, except it seems like the right alt key still works as alt in combination with other keys.  For example, if I just press the right alt key, a space is inserted.  However, if I press the right alt key at the same time as the f key, my browser's "file" dropdown opens.  This is a pain when typing fast, because frequently my right alt (mapped to space) overlaps with other letters, triggering a key combo and doing something unwanted.

When I do `xmodmap -pke | grep Alt_R`, I get no results, so it looks like nothing else is left to recognize `Alt_R`, so I am not sure how to remap `Alt_R` for key combinations as well.

Comment: what's the output of `xmodmap` command before mapping?